# Custom compare function for stable_sort

Tags: c++, stl

I want to sort an array of `int32_t`, such that all positive numbers (including zero) appears first, followed by all negative number.  The relative order of +ve and -ve numbers in the output should be in the same relative order as the input.  E.g.

```
Input  : 9, 4, -2, -1, 5, 0, -5, -3, 2 <br>
Expected Output : 9, 4, 5, 0, 2, -2, -1, -5, -3
```

However, I am getting the following output:

```
Actual output : 2 0 5 4 9 -3 -5 -1 -2 <br>
```

The output is partially accurate, +ve then -ve, but the list of +ve and -ve numbers are reversed.  Can someone please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


bool comp(int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs)
{
    if ( (lhs < 0) && (rhs >= 0) )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int32_t> input{9, 4, -2, -1, 5, 0, -5, -3, 2};

    // sort +ve, then -ve
    stable_sort(input.begin(), input.end(), comp);
    for (int32_t i : input)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Your expected output has a 2 at the end, after the negatives. That's not correct, is it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are correct.  Updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparison function does not meet the requirements of a strict weak ordering. Specifically, irreflexivity. That is, for all `a`,

> comp(a, a) == false

In your function, for example, comp(0, 0) would return true. Try this:

```
bool comp(int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs)
{
    if (lhs < 0)
        return false;
    return rhs < 0;
}
```

But really, the operation you're describing is a partition. You would be better suited to use `std::stable_partition` with a predicate that checks if values are >= 0.

```
auto ge_0 = [](int A) { return A >= 0; };
std::stable_parition(input.begin(), input.end(), ge_0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  +1 for mentioning use of the correction stl function - stable_partition(), which give me O(N) complexity, as opposed to (possibly) O(NlogN).

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparator function to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool comp(int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs) {
    if ((lhs ^ rhs) >= 0)    // same sign: don't change
        return false;
    else
        return lhs > rhs;
}

int main() {
    vector<int32_t> input{9, 4, -2, -1, 5, 0, -5, -3, 2};
    stable_sort(input.begin(), input.end(), comp);
    for (int32_t i : input)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ideone [`DEMO`](https://www.ideone.com/F2ZreY)